# What's the difference between & and && in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, logical-operators, short-circuiting

What is the difference between the `&` and `&&` logical operators in MATLAB?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The single ampersand & is the logical AND operator.  The double ampersand && is again a logical AND operator that employs short-circuiting behaviour. Short-circuiting just means the second operand (right hand side) is evaluated only when the result is not fully determined by the first operand (left hand side)

A & B (A and B are evaluated)

A && B (B is only evaluated if A is true)

Comment: On caveat: `&` can operate on arrays but `&&` can only operate on scalars.

Comment: Side note: after 15 years working with Matlab almost daily I always use '&' and it has never bitten me in the ass. OTOH, I know many people who get annoyed using '&&' because they have to remember it isn't universal (yes I realize that '&' isn't as efficient because it doesn't short circuit but I pretty much never daisy-chain my operands so the savings nowadays are negligible).

Comment: @neuronet it isn't really about efficiency, more that it permits a construct where the first expression guarantees a condition without which the second expression may cause a run-time error. e.g. 
 `d != 0 && 1/d` vs  `d !=0 & 1/d` - the first guarantees no division by zero, the second doesn't.

Comment: Be warned! `&` and `|` _do_ short-circuit, sometimes. [Quoth the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html): "When you use the element-wise `&` and `|` operators in the context of an `if` or `while` loop expression (and _only_ in that context), they use short-circuiting to evaluate expressions." This bizarre behavior is peculiar to MATLAB and is not shared by any other language that uses these operators.

Comment: This answer is incomplete and inaccurate. `&` does short-circuit if in an `if` statement. And `&&` takes scalar inputs. [@Loren's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1393606/7328782) is correct.

Answer (score 39):

`&&` and `||` take scalar inputs and short-circuit always.  `|` and `&` take array inputs and short-circuit only in if/while statements.  For assignment, the latter do not short-circuit.

See [these doc pages](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) for more information.

Comment: Do you have any information on which Matlab versions shortcut `&` and `|` in if/while statements? It does not seem to be the case in R2012b and R2014a.

Comment: @Loren any idea *why* they designed one to work with scalars only? It seems strange...

Comment: @neuronet: You cannot short-circuit if you operate on arrays.

Answer (score 18):

As already mentioned by others, `&` is a [logical AND operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html) and `&&` is a [short-circuit AND operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html). They differ in how the operands are evaluated *as well as whether or not they operate on arrays or scalars:*

- `&` (AND operator) and `|` (OR operator) can operate on *arrays* in an element-wise fashion.
- `&&` and `||` are short-circuit versions for which the second operand is evaluated only when the result is not fully determined by the first operand. These can only operate on *scalars*, not arrays.

Answer (score 9):

Both are logical AND operations.  The && though, is a "short-circuit" operator.  From the MATLAB docs:

> They are short-circuit operators in that they evaluate their second operand only when the result is not fully determined by the first operand.

See more [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/f16-6011.html).

Answer (score 7):

`&` is a logical elementwise operator, while `&&` is a logical short-circuiting operator (which can only operate on scalars).

For example (pardon my syntax).

If..

```
A = [True True False True]
B = False
A & B = [False False False False]
```

..or..

```
B = True
A & B = [True True False True]
```

For `&&`, the right operand is only calculated if the left operand is true, and the result is a single boolean value.

**`x = (b ~= 0) && (a/b > 18.5)`**

Hope that's clear.

Comment: It's not bitwise, it's element-wise.

Comment: Did I just get well-actually'd 10 years later? 

Comment: Well, this question has gotten ~115k views so far, which means a lot of people have read misinformation here. Many of these answers are incomplete or contain wrong information. All you need to do is fix your answer or delete it. BTW: `bitand` is the bitwise logical AND operator in MATLAB.

Answer (score 4):

&& and || are [short circuit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) operators operating on scalars.  & and | operate on arrays, and [use short-circuiting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html) only in the context of `if` or `while` loop expressions.

Answer (score 2):

A good rule of thumb when constructing arguments for use in conditional statements (IF, WHILE, etc.) is to *always* use the &&/|| forms, unless there's a very good reason not to.  There are two reasons...

1. As others have mentioned, the short-circuiting behavior of &&/|| is similar to most C-like languages. That similarity / familiarity is generally considered a point in its favor.
2. Using the && or || forms *forces* you to write the full code for deciding your intent for vector arguments.  When a = [1 0 0 1] and b = [0 1 0 1], is a&b true or false?  I can't remember the rules for MATLAB's &, can you?  Most people can't.  On the other hand, if you use && or ||, you're FORCED to write the code "in full" to resolve the condition.

Doing this, rather than relying on MATLAB's resolution of vectors in & and |, leads to code that's a little bit more verbose, but a LOT safer and easier to maintain.

Comment: +1, but it should be noted that your answer only applies to cases where you **want** the final result of the operation to be scalar. There are many uses for & and | where && and || are useless because they can't return arrays, for example when doing fancy indexing like "selecting all r between 1 and 2: `r((r<2)&(r<2))`".

Comment: Good point, Jonas.  I was thinking of conditionals, not "logical indexing," (the MATLAB term for the "fancy indexing" you mentioned) when I wrote this.  I changed the first sentence of my post to reflect that.  Thanks for the reminder!