# What does the matlab operator "|" mean?

Tags: matlab

I'm confused with the matlab operator `|`. Could you say what does it actually mean?

Suppose that I've 2 image matrices `image1` and `image2` so what would `image3=image1|image2;` mean?

Thanks

Comment: You should read the [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operators.html#f0-38948) for MATLAB logical operators...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By extension of operators used in early languages (C, C++), broadly, in MATLAB which is derived from C,  `|` has the standard meaning, that is, `OR` operator of boolean logic.

As for your comment about `element-wise multiplication or division in matrix we use . as well, but for what purpose do we use |?`, if we use `.|`, then it is equivalent to `|`, just like `.+` and `.-`. All these operators require the operands to be of equal size. But, historically due to the same symbol for normal multiplication and matrix multiplication, there are two symbols, `*` and `.*` respectively. These symbols `*` and `.*` are totally different, so as to avoid the ambiguity in logic of normal multiplication and matrix multiplication. Similarly, it is ditto for division operation.

Equivalent operations:

`.+` == `+`

`.-` == `-`

`.|` == `|`

Not equivalent operations:

`.*` != `*`

`./` != `/`

Answer (score 2):

This operator stands for element-wise logical or operation: see [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorselementwise.html).

Suppose `image1` and `image2` are logical matrices (with entries either `true` or `false`), then `image3 = image1 | image2;` means that each entry in `image3` is a logical or of the respective entries in `image1` and `image2`

Comment: So, I understand it's element-wise but for what operation? I mean like for element-wise multiplication or division in matrix we use `.` as well, but for what purpose do we use `|`?

Comment: @the_naive since logical operations (`|`, `&`) has no "matrix" interpretation, then they don't have the explicit element-wise dot in fornt of them. **But** you should note that `|`,`&` are DIFFERENT than `||` and `&&`!

Comment: FYI, related questions: [What's the difference between & and && in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379415) and [What's the difference between | and || in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183385)

Answer (score 2):

Element-wise logical OR operation

so:

`[1 0] | [1 1]` would result in `[ 1 1 ]`

and,

`[0 1] | [0 0]` would result in `[ 0 1 ]`.

In your case `image3` would be a matrix of the size of `image1` and `image2` holding trues (1) or falses as obtained by a element-wise logical OR.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two equally sized matrices `image1` and `image2` (can contain logicals but can also contain other values)

Then `image3 = image1 | image2` will give you the so called 'logical mask' of `image1` and `image2`.

This means that image 3 is equal to 1 (true) at points where at least one of the images is a nonzero number, and equal to 0 (false) if they are both zero.

Example:

```
image1 = [   0 255;
           166   0]
image2 = [-123   0;
           255   0]
image3 = image1 | image2
% Will give as output:
[1 1
 1 0]
```