# Removing some indexes of a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 2D matrix, `A`, each row representing a sample of signal,

I want to filter it by removing the samples having *mean* more and less than a threshold.

so I calculate the mean like `m = mean(A');`

then I want to do something like

```
A(m > 2 || m < 1 , :) = [];
```

Which faces with an error,

I tried doing like,

```
A(m > 2 , :) = [];
A(m < 1 , :) = [];
```

But I realized that after executing the first line, the indexes change and ...

So what can I do?

Comment: You should take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183385/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-matlab) regarding _the difference between `|` and `||`_. (tl;dr: | can operate on arrays but || can only operate on scalars).

On a side note: in order to combat the index change after `A(m > 2 , :) = [];`, you can just run `m = mean(A');` again to recalculate the indices.

Comment: @Dev-iL, Good point about using the `mean` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are suggesting you use element-wise or instead of scalar.

This:

```
A(m > 2 | m < 1 , :) = [];
```

Not this:

```
A(m > 2 || m < 1 , :) = [];
```

But, as with your other question, I strongly recommend using a dimension argument to mean instead of transposing the input matrix to mean:

```
m = mean(A,2).'; % NOT m = mean(A');
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
 A(m > 2,:) = NaN;
 A(m < 1,:) = NaN;
 A(any(isnan(A),2),:) = [];
```

I don't know if it is efficient enough, but it did the job.