# Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values

Tags: matlab, logical-operators

I have a simple problem that I'm looking for a fast implementation in Matlab. I have an array of values, let's say:

```
 a = floor(rand(5,5).*255)
```

I then have a similarly sized threshold array, let's say it's:

```
a_thresh = floor(rand(5,5).*255)
```

For values within `a` if they are 0.5x smaller than the corresponding value in `a_thresh` I want the output to be 0 - similarly for 1.2x the value in `a_thresh` should also be set to zero, *i.e.*:

```
a(a < a_thresh.*0.4) = 0
a(a > a_thresh.*1.2) = 0
```

For values between 0.4x and 0.5x and 1.0x and 1.2x I want a proportional amount and else where between 0.5 and 1.0 I want to use the value of `a` unaltered. I thought I could use something like the following:

```
 a(a>= a_thresh .* 0.4 && a <a_thresh.* 0.5) = ((a - a_thresh.*0.4)/(a_thresh.*0.5 a_thresh.*0.4)) .* a;
```

However, I get an error that says:

> Operands to || and && operations must be convertible to logical scalar values

Any advice on how to solve this? Obviously I could use loops to do this and it would be trivial, but I want to keep the code vectorized.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The thing about `&&` is that it can operate only on *scalars*, whereas `&` can operate on arrays as well. You should change the `&&` to `&` to make it work (you can read more about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379415/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-matlab.)).

**Update:**
Regarding your second problem described in a comment: the number of elements on the left is different because you're using indices (selecting only certain elements), and on the right you're working with the entire matrix `a` and `a_thresh`.

You need to use indices in both sides, so I suggest storing it in a variable and then use it as an array subscript, along these lines:

```
idx = (a >= a_thresh*0.4 & a < a_thresh*0.5);
a(idx) = ((a(idx)-a_thresh(idx)*0.4) ./ (a_thresh(idx)*0.5*a_thresh(idx)*0.4)) .* a(idx);
```

I'm not sure if the calculation itself is correct, so I'll leave it to you to check.

Comment: Fantastic - that addresses the &/&& issue - I some how didn't know that, thanks! Now I have a small problem that the number of elements on the right is different from the left. Is there a smart way of fixing this?

Comment: Many, many thanks Eitan - your solution works perfectly - and is clearly general enough that I can see how I can use it elsewhere in my Matlab work