# if statement in MatLab environment

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I used the following simple code to check the properties of `elseif` command in MATLAB:

```
x = 10;
if x < 0
   y = x;
elseif 0 <= x < 2
   y = 3*x;
elseif x >= 2
   y = 8*x;
end
y
```

I would have expected the result of this to be `80` since `x >= 2`. But something amazing happened! The result is `30`, not `80`!

But why? Any ideas?

Update: when I change the code (as recommended in the answers) to

```
x = 10;
if x < 0
   y = x;
elseif (0 <= x) && ( x < 2 )
   y = 3*x;
elseif x >= 2
   y = 8*x;
end
y
```

I get `80` as expected. It's that double condition that threw me off.

Comment: Thanks @Floris. I got the point.

Comment: @floris I really like your updates on my question. Thanks.

Comment: @user2667048 - glad to hear it. I am deleting my "old" comments now since the question is now clear, and there is no need to preserve the chatter for future visitors...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
if 0 <= x < 2
```

you are really writing (without realizing it)

```
if (0 <= x) < 2
```

Which is evaluated as

```
if (true) < 2
```

which is true, since `true` evaluates to `1`.

So here is what is happening, line by line:

```
x = 10;            % x is set to 10
if x < 0           % false
   y = x;          % not executed
elseif 0 <= x < 2  % condition is (true) < 2, thus true
   y = 3*x;        % y is set to 3*x, i.e. 30
elseif x >= 2      % since we already passed a condition, this is not evaluated
   y = 8*x;        % skipped
end                % end of composite if 
y                  % display the value of y - it should be 30
```

As an aside, when you use scalars, you should really use the `&&` operator, not the `&` operator. See for example [What's the difference between & and && in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379415/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-matlab)

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake in copying the code. Thanks for your description.

Comment: +1 for the effort to make a detailed explanation for such a simple problem

Answer (score 2):

`0 <= x < 2` doesn't behave as you may expect. Use `(0 <= x) & (x < 2)`

How does `0 <= x < 2` behave? It is evaluated from left to right. First `0 <= x` gives `1` (true), and then `1 < 2` gives `1` (true). So the condition gives true, not false as you would expect.

Since the second condition in your code (`0 <= x < 2`) is true, you get a value `30` for `y`. Changing the condition to `(0 <= x) & (x < 2)` you get a value `80` for `y`.