# Not equal (~=) in MATLAB! Unexpected MATLAB operator

Tags: matlab

I'm writing some code and my assignment is:

> & and |. The "and" and "or" operators are simplistic, but very
>   powerful when used well. &, or "and", simply compares two logical
>   values and returns a single true if both of the logicals it was
>   comparing are true. |, or "or" (which is shift + the key right above
>   Enter), simply compares two logical values and returns a true if
>   either of its compared values are true. Use this knowledge to find if
>   num is both a positive number and not equal to 1.

SO I wrote:

```
B = num > 0 & ~= 1
```

where num is some positive integer

This is the error code I get:

> Error: File: ABCs_logicals.m Line: 40 Column: 14 Unexpected MATLAB
>   operator.

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: What does `%`, or anything in the first paragraph, except the last sentence, have to do with your question? What you did wrong is make up some arbitrary syntax and expect it to work. You need `B = num > 0 && num ~= 1`

Comment: I recommend typing `help &` or `help |` in your command window and reading the actual documentation too.

Comment: I will also recommend reading my tutorial on MATLAB before asking any more questions here.  What you are asking is quite trivial and can be found by reading any help file on syntax or the documentation:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/q7ozdbphl727s6c/ELE532_MATLABTutorial_Full.ppt?dl=1

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in natural language, you have to write out a complete comparison on both sides of the boolean operators, that's how it works. So you can't leave out `num` in the second part like you did.

Matlab complains about `~=` because it didn't expect that symbol right after the `&` operator.

Try this instead:

```
B = num > 0 & num ~= 1
```

Comment: If I can nitpick, use `&&` when you're dealing with scalar numbers (such as this example), and use `&` for doing element-wise logical AND for matrices/vectors.  In fact, if you develop code using MATLAB's editor, it should give you a warning when you try using `&` on scalars.  Either way, well done!

Comment: @rayryeng: Hmm I wouldn't recommend using `&&` in this particular case, as the instructions explicitly mention `&`. A `&&` would look like OP got the answer from the internet. Oh wait.. :P Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379415/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-matlab) question for the &/&& difference.

Comment: True enough! My guess is that later, they'll learn about vectorized operations, but I use && for scalars as it tells me that I'm comparing to scalars as a sanity check and I'm not comparing with any other type. However that post is also true about what it says. I just forgot (until now)