# Intersect operations with fractional values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, octave

I want to intersect some fractional values:

```
frac_value = intersect (find(xmin > 0) , find(xmin < 1))
```

where `xmin` is a large vector of fractional values. I have printed xmin values till `0.16f`, where some of them are showing values `0.0000000000000000`, but `frac_value` returning it's position. I have no idea why. How can I perfectly get the positions of fractional values only?

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you wrote is a bit obfuscated.  One way to make this more clear is to do:

```
frac_value = find(xmin > 0 & xmin < 1);
```

What you are essentially doing is finding the **indices** of `xmin` that are both greater than 0 and less than 1.  Instead of using `intersect`, just use `find`.

---

If you want to find the positions of where these values lie, then the above code is perfectly acceptable.   However, I suspect that this is not what you're intending due to the title of your post.  If you want to find **the actual** fractional values, you need to **index** into `xmin` with `frac_value` instead:

```
values = xmin(frac_value);
```

---

However, I wouldn't use `find` or `intersect` here at all.  What is more efficient and simpler is to use **logical** indexing without `find` or `intersect` (which I will argue is faster performance-wise):

```
values = xmin(xmin > 0 & xmin < 1);
```

`values` should now contain the values of `xmin` that are between 0 and 1, rather than the locations of them.

Comment: I have another question, what should i use in matlab when I want to use logical and (& or &&) , logical or (| or ||)?

Comment: there're some info for `&, &&, |, ||` here: https://truongnghiem.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/short-circuit-logical-operators-matlab/

Comment: @Cherry - Check here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379415/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-matlab

Comment: Sorry, it is still showing the same problem. like 'frac_value' are showing those position which are actually '0.0000000000000000' , do not know what to do

Comment: rayryeng: sure I can. But probably I do not know how to accept an answer :P :P

Comment: click on the approved icon under the vote number to accept an answer :p

Comment: @Cherry - Try changing the format: `format long g`.  `format long g` only shows floating point decimal places if merited.  It automatically figures out the best display type for you given the number.