# Plotting a function in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, plot, matlab-figure

I'm interested in plotting the following function in Matlab, but without succes.

[image]

I can't manage to plot the points.

```
 x = -1:0.1:3;
 if (x<=1)
     y = x*x-x+1
     plot(x,y)
 else
     y = 2*x+3
     plot(x,y)
 end
```

Comment: Look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533221/piecewise-function-plot-in-matlab) for some tips.

Comment: What should f(x=1) be equal to?

Comment: You're using an `if` statement in conjunction with a vector.  What do you expect will happen?

Comment: @brodroll technically both 1 and 5, since both branches of the function contain 1 in their domain. A mathematician would be concerned; I, being a physicist, do not care too much about limit and boundary values in singular points. If it really mattered the domains should be changed.

Comment: Related question+answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790802/how-to-make-a-graph-of-a-three-branches-function-in-matlab/30845312#30845312

Comment: @Adriaan I bet it won't be a problem. It is just something that called my attention when I layed my eyes onto it. Technically you can't even call f a function the way it is written unless, as you said, the domains are changed

Comment: If the answer below helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` statement you defines takes the condition for the *entire array*, which means **all** entries should adhere to the statement. Since only the first 21 adhere to the condition posed, the `if` statement goes to the `else` and plots a straight line.

Your equation for the first line is incorrect, since `x*x` results in an error since MATLAB assumes this to be a matrix multiplication and the sizes are not correct for that. The reason you are not seeing this error is due to the `if` statement, since, as explained above, that never reaches this line. You should change that equation using the dot-multiplication, which does things element-wise as opposed to array/matrix-wise.

The equation for the second line is correct.

If your `if/else` statement would be correct your first plot would be overwritten by the second, since you did not specify the `hold on` switch to figures.

As a note I also used the semicolon `;` after each statement, which prevents it from printing the output of a line to the console.

```
x1 = [-1:0.01:1].';
x2 = [1:0.01:3].';
y1 = x1.^2-x1+1;
y2 = 2*x2+3;

figure;
hold on
plot(x1,y1)
plot(x2,y2)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: The `else` in the original code is causing major grief, I wouldn't say that it is correct except for `hold on`.

Comment: And "you were overwriting your plot of the first part with the second bit" definitely does not apply to the code in the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for pointing this out. I addressed both points in the answer.

Comment: You could also mention that his else statement is never entered for an x value of 1. if(x<= 1) includes the 1, so the else wouldn't be entered for this value. I realize your solution avoids the if/else all together, just something to note.

Comment: @BenVoigt not true, try running it for yourself. You get a nice straight line from x=-1 to x=3, because *not all*  x<=1 it does actually execute the statement within `else`.

Comment: @Adriaan: Yes, I just found the documentation.  Indeed it implies an `all()`, not an `any()`.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html

Comment: @Dustiny: `else` isn't entered for individual values.  Control either flows to the then-part, or the else-part.