# Plot a specific two input elements equation

Tags: matlab, math, plot, anonymous-function, graphic

How to plot the equation below in Matlab.
There are two factors in this equation.

Note that k is a scalar number in (-1,1).

So given an x value, a double value (-infinity,+infinity).

I need to plot a graphic of this function.

```
if x>0              plot (1-k)x
else (case x<=0)    plot(1+k)x
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a graph of a three-branches function in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790802/how-to-make-a-graph-of-a-three-branches-function-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
k = 3 - randi(3); %random number between -1-0-1 (thanks op)
x = -1e6:1e6; %a very long vecot
y = zeros(1,length(x)); %prelocate y
ind = find(x); %find the indeces where x>0
y(ind) = (1- k) * x(ind);
ind = find (x<=0);
y(ind) = (1+k) * x(ind);
plot(x,y);%plot
```

Comment: Hey nice @Ronen Cohen, but using your version to a float value in [-1,1], doesnt work very well, cause you make ans vector 2x2, and will be a error using it. If I want simulate the integer state, and this case k={-1,0,1}, I'm using  randi(3)-2. Thank you for want to help me!  ans =

    0.5315   -0.4685
   -0.4685    0.5315

>> (rand*(-1))^(randi(1,2))

Answer (score 0):

I like anonymous functions - can improve readability.

```
f = @(x,k) (1-k).*x.*(x>0) + (1+k).*x.*(x<=0)
plot(x,f(x,k))
```

Note the use of (x>0) and (x<=0) to handle different cases.

Comment: Could I use your code to plot in Matlab? I dont know this form using @, is it a parametric way?

Comment: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html

Comment: Yes you can. Just define x and k to something first.

Comment: My problem is that I want plot every case for this function,  k={-1,0,1} and x being a point continuous value in [-1000, 1000] just for test. I think I need three plots one for each case of k.