# How to correctly create function handle for multi-variable piecewise function?

Tags: matlab, function, anonymous-function, piecewise, function-handle

I want to create a function_handle using an anonymous function for the following:

```
f(x,y) = 1, if 2 <= x <= 3 and y = 1,
f(x,y) = 0, otherwise
```

I thought I could just do:

```
f @(x,y) 1.*((x >= 2) && (x <= 3) & (y == 1));
```

When I try to evaluate this function by: `f(ones(3,1),ones(3,1))`, I get the error:

> Operands to the `||` and `&&` operators must be convertible to logical
>   scalar values.

I also noticed that my function seems to work fine when I only input scalar `x` and `y`. 
My question is: How do I correctly define my function handle so that it works for vectors/arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a single `&` here if you intend to use `x` and `y` as vectors/matrices of the *same* dimensions.

```
f = @(x,y) (x>=2) & (x<=3) & (y==1);  %Multiplying by 1 is also not needed here
```

---

Recommended reading: [What's the difference between & and && in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379415/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-matlab)