# Is there an alternative of and() in Matlab that does not check syntax and returns a false as soon as the first false is found?

Tags: matlab

Is there a convenient alternative of `and()` in Matlab that does not check existence, number of input or output arugments, and returns a false as soon as the first `false` is found without evaluating the expressions in subsequent inputs?

For example, I would like

```
and(0,a),
and(0,error()),
```

to both return false as opposed to returning error messages. Once an earliest input argument returns `false`, I have no use of subsequent input arguments and I am happy to ignore syntax errors. But Matlab isn't.

(The more likely scenario for me is that the `false` case of preceding inputs cover any syntax errors in later inputs.)

Is there a way around this? If I write an alternative of `and()` with a (Matlab) loop on `varargin`, will the alternative be slower?

Comment: Use `&&` operator .

Comment: Why don't you use `if else` ?

Comment: @rahnema1: `if else` can't be made into a `function_handle`.

Comment: Just use ordinary functions and if it is needed you can take its handle.

Comment: @rahnema1: I am asking for the alternative to that..  For `&&`, does `&&` behave the same way as `and()` other than syntax check?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379415/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-matlab).

Comment: Thanks for the link. That answers the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the && operator solves your problem,

```
0 && a

0 && error()
```

will return

```
ans =

  logical

   0
```

Of course, even when `a` is undefined.

Caveat: `and()` can take (syntax checked) array arguments while `&&` cannot. The different answers and comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379415/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-matlab) explain in more details.

Comment: Is there any difference between `and()` and `&&`? And is there any restriction on the use of `&&` syntax wise?

Comment: `and()` is the same as `&`, this is, the logical operator. `&&` is instead a logical and operator with short-circuiting, which means that is does exactly what you want. It only executes until the first false is found. There is no syntax restriction compared to `&`.

Answer (score 0):

The MATLAB interpreter (just like any other interpreter I’ve come across) parses all the input arguments to a function before calling the function. The function is passed the results of evaluating the arguments. Therefore, it is not possible to have a function control which of its input arguments are parsed.

There is no functional equivalent to `&&`, the short-circuit logical AND. The function `and` is equivalent to `&` and does not short-circuit.

Comment: Why does the interpreter parse all arguments by necessity?

Comment: @Argyll: OK, so maybe not strictly necessary, I guess. But delaying evaluation would certainly lead to a more complex interpreter, and delayed and confusing error messages.

Comment: Is error message the reason towards necessity then? Why would it be more complex if it does less checks?

Comment: @Argyll: There is also the expectation of execution order: if functions have side-effects, for example print something to the screen, in what order do you expect these functions to do their thing? `fun(a(), b())`.

Comment: evaluate functions as nested expressions in the order of the expressions? start with first line of `fun` until `a` is required; when `a` is required, evaluate `a()`, which may potentially include `fun` as well. Isn't that natural of a functional language?

Comment: So depending on `fun` either `a` or `b` would be called first? I’m not sure I would appreciate that from a language. Also note that in a functional programming language, functions don’t have side effects. MATLAB is not a functional programming language.

Comment: I am not sure if you necessarily need functions to be unable to modify variables that outlive the function in a functional language. And yes, depending on `fun`, which also means depending on the context in which `fun` is called, either `a` or `b` may be called first or not at all. Otherwise, it's restrictive, isn't it? The need for short-circuiting in logical operators is an example.

Comment: Rather, whenever the order of evaluation is reversed by some special rule, instead of the order of expressions themselves, it is an extra special rule to have to memorize. But yes, I can see why type checking is at the beginning. It is probably easier to implement. But it shouldn't be more efficient. When an expression throws error, input type can be checked then. It's not necessarily less efficient.

Comment: The definition of functional programming languages is the elimination of side effects. There is no state. Regarding evaluation order: you’ll find all imperative languages evaluate the arguments before evaluating the function itself. MATLAB, Python, C, C++, Java, ... I don’t know any languages that don’t do this, so for me it is the natural thing to do.

Comment: Scheme. . . . (hit char count)