# How to do bit-wise AND between multi-dimensional arrays using armadillo in C++?

Tags: c++, armadillo

My task is to rewrite the codes `is_valid = (DoG == DoG_max) & (DoG >= threshold);` in matlab using armadillo with C++. The `DoG` and `DoG_max` are multidimensional arrays with the same size `907 x 1210 x 5`, and the `threshold is a scalar`.

According to the [documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#operators) of **armadillo**, the *bit-wise equal operator* `==` is built-in and the *bit-wise greater than* operation can be replaced with [the member function](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#clean) `.clean()` which is to set all elements but the ones higher than the threshold to zeros.

Here is my codes:

```
// arma::cube DoG, DoG_max;  // Size: 907 x 1210 x 5.
arma::ucube is_valid(arma::size(DoG), arma::fill::zeros);
DoG.clean(threshold);
for (int s = 0; s < is_valid.n_slices; ++s) {
  is_valid.slice(s) = (DoG.slice(s) == DoG_max.slice(s));
}
```

What confuses me is the *bit-wise AND* operator, which is not provided by armadillo. I want to know whether the logic of my codes is consistent with  `is_valid = (DoG == DoG_max) & (DoG >= threshold);`?  Based on my investigation, the result is different to that in matlab.

If there're solutions using Eigen, please also tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` operator is implemented in Armadillo, but strangely it's not documented. Try this as a translation of your Matlab code:

```
ucube is_valid = (DoG == DoG_max) && (DoG >= threshold);
```

In case you want a scalar output, try this:

```
bool is_valid = all(vectorise((DoG == DoG_max) && (DoG >= threshold)));
```

There is some confusion in the meaning of "&" and "&&" between C++ and Matlab. In C++, "&" means "bitwise AND", while "&&" means "logical AND".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

In Matlab, "&" and "&&" both mean "logical AND", but have slightly different evaluation depending on the context: [What's the difference between & and && in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379415/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-matlab)